# is SVN configuration possible in local/lan server?

Tags: svn, webserver, lan

I want know is there any way to configure a SVN over a LAN sever(web server with php+mysql+apache configured), in LINUX, Windows.
my requirement is to build a small web server with SVN facility in locally.

i know the tortoise svn configuration. But how can  be possible in LAN(locally).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The [Subversion Book](http://svnbook.org/) has an excellent [chapter on server configuration](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.5/svn.serverconfig.html). I suggest you start there. The book is pretty thorough and understandable. Or if you're a Windows kind of guy, you might want to take a look at [VisualSVN Server](http://www.visualsvn.com/server/) which can be set up and administered in a point-and-click manner.